# Chart.js - Creating multiple charts on one page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla, chart.js

I would like to use [chart.js](http://chartjs.org) in my joomla-component called "bestia".
To do so I imported chart.js as media-element in the manifest.xml.

I'm calling the js by doing the following:

`JHtml::script(Juri::root() . 'media/com_hostinghelden/chartjs/Chart.js');`

Now I would like to use a helper to shorten things up a bit. My helper should draw a graph...

```php
abstract class JHtmlGraphs 
{
    public function draw($title = NULL, $labelset = NULL, $data = NULL, $data2 = NULL)
    {
        $script = "<script> var barChartData_$title = { labels : [ {$labelset} ], datasets : [ { fillColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)', strokeColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.8)', highlightFill: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.75)', highlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)', data : [ $data ] }, { fillColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)', strokeColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,0.8)', highlightFill : 'rgba(151,187,205,0.75)', highlightStroke : 'rgba(151,187,205,1)', data : [ $data2 ] } ] }; window.onload = function(){ var ctx_$title = document.getElementById('canvas_$title').getContext('2d'); window.myBar = new Chart(ctx_$title).Bar(barChartData_$title, { responsive : true }); } </script>";
        $canvas = "<div style='width: 100%'><canvas id='canvas_$title' height='20' width='20'></canvas></div>";
        return $script . $canvas;
    }
}
```

Well, if I call this Jhtml-Graphs, the graph is rendered correctly:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('graphs.draw', "Titel", $labelset, $data, $data2);  ?>
```

But if I want to add a second graph to my page, the first graph is no longer shown:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('graphs.draw', "Titel2", $labelset, $data, $data2); ?>
```

What can I do?

Comment: No :-( There are no errors in the console...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redeclaring `window.onload` function. Thats why you will draw only one (last) chart.

```
window.onload = function(){ 
    var ctx_$title = document.getElementById('canvas_$title').getContext('2d');                                    
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx_$title).Bar(barChartData_$title, { responsive : true }); 

}
```

What you can do to fix that. Im proposing to change `JHtmlGraphs` class as following:

```
    abstract class JHtmlGraphs 
{
    private $titles = array();

    public function draw($title = NULL, $labelset = NULL, $data = NULL, $data2 = NULL)
    {
        $script = "<script> var barChartData_$title = { labels : [ {$labelset} ], datasets : [ { fillColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)', strokeColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.8)', highlightFill: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.75)', highlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)', data : [ $data ] }, { fillColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)', strokeColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,0.8)', highlightFill : 'rgba(151,187,205,0.75)', highlightStroke : 'rgba(151,187,205,1)', data : [ $data2 ] } ] };</script>";
        $canvas = "<div style='width: 100%'><canvas id='canvas_$title' height='20' width='20'></canvas></div>";

        $this->titles[] = $title; //storing titles
        return $script . $canvas;
    }

    public function finishDrawing() {
        $launchCharts = '';
        foreach($this->titles as $title) {
            $launchCharts .= "var ctx_$title = document.getElementById('canvas_$title').getContext('2d'); window.myBar_$title = new Chart(ctx_$title).Bar(barChartData_$title, { responsive : true });";
        }
        $this->titles = array();

        $script =  "<script>window.onload = function(){ $launchCharts }</script>";
        return $script;
    }
}
```

I modified your scripts. Now your `onload` function will be generated one time, from `finishDrawing` method:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('graphs.draw', "Titel", $labelset, $data, $data2);  ?>
<?php echo JHtml::_('graphs.draw', "Titel2", $labelset, $data, $data2); ?>
```

And somewhere at the bottom you have to call new function:

```
<?php echo JHtml::finishDrawing(); //you better know than me how to call this function?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I'm not that kind of javascript-expert... How can I fix that? How can I use my helper to draw multiple charts without redeclaring window.onload ?

Comment: @user3755325 ive updated my answer. I hope there are no errors - not tested.